# Xero API - Single Payment to Multiple Invoices and Credit Notes

Tags: c#

Using the Xero API on C#, I tried to create a single Payment for a list of invoices and credit notes.
I noticed that the Payment object only allows one invoice or one credit note which is not practical.
Can you explain how I can achieve this in Xero?

Comment: Please note: My use case is a single xero payment to a collection of invoices and credit notes.

Comment: See following : https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/items